# Supply voltage 5V issue from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: voltage

I have a sensor connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 and I see some variations of the signals which is not expected. These variations seems to be due to the supply voltage 5 V from the Raspberry Pi.

The 5 V signal has both high frequency oscillations (between about 4.9 - 5 V), and a long term drift (over hours I see it slowly dropping). 
Does anyone have any idea about what is causing it and how to solve it?

The sensor has two voltage outputs connected to a ADC. The ADC is connected to the 5 V PWR, to ground and to SCL/SDA of Raspberry Pi

Comment: What is the specification of your power supply?

Answer (score 4):

The subject of ADC error is both wide and deep. Engineers have built careers on studying, quantifying, measuring and resolving ADC error. If you "Google" terms such as `adc error analysis`, or `adc error correction`, you'll find enough highly technical and/or scholarly information to keep you occupied for quite some time - [for example](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa013/slaa013.pdf). But the bottom line is that power supplies can make a huge difference in ADC performance.

The description you gave of your PS sounds like a recipe for poor measurements. All switching power supplies will produce some noise, and HF oscillations "come with the territory" as the laws of physics dictate that the "off-then-on" nature of the supply will propagate to the output as oscillations. These oscillations are not necessarily problematic as long as they are not "too large"; "too large" being relative to the accuracy required. What is "too large" for your case may be determined by reading the data sheet for the ADC chip you're using; you should refer to that for your power supply specifications. One potential cure for taming the oscillations is a high quality, low ESR capacitor (tantalum, for example) that is placed as close as possible to your ADC circuitry.

Your comment about long-term drift ("over hours I see it slowly dropping") is what seems to be the strongest indicator that you have a sub-standard power supply. Again, some drift is normal and expected, but I get the idea that yours may be greater than that. I know of no easy way to correct drift in a power supply - except to replace it!

If your supply is one that you bought for your RPi, there is a [decent chance it's not very good quality](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations). And as mentioned, the only real solution here is to buy a better quality supply. For this, you may have to venture outside the "Raspberry Pi marketplace".

Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to ask additional questions, or post a Comment if something is unclear. Also, you may wish to consider [adding a schematic](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question) to your question if you need more specific answers.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, as you said it is a "poor" setup. I have been generic in the description on purpose. I can say you were right, the problem is the power supplied by r.pi that is not constant. I also notices a drop of voltage when opening an excel sheet. Problem solved with an external power supply.

Comment: Very good, I think you're on the right track. Oh - one other thing: If you've not done so, please read [the site tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).